# python generate random list starting with

Tags: python

In the following arr i want generate random numbers which start with "1" and "2" how to do this..I want always to start with "1" and "2" and the rest can be random

```
example output : 123456789
                 123478956
                 124568973
                 123789456   



 arr=["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]

 for i in range(50):
   lines = random.sample(arr, 9) //I want always to start with "1" and "2" and the rest can be random
   print "%s"%''.join(lines)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concat `['1', '2']` with the rest 8 elements shuffled.

```
>>> ['1', '2'] + random.sample(arr[2:], 7)
['1', '2', '6', '3', '8', '7', '9', '5', '4']
```

Comment: the elements after the first two will never include ``1``

Answer (score 0):

Alter your selection statement

```
lines = random.sample(arr[:2],1) + random.sample(arr, 8)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `random.randrange()` Here you have to give starting and ending numbers.

```
import random

for i in range(50):
        lines = random.randrange(120000000,130000000)
        print lines
```

this will give you 50 random numbers starting with 1 and 2

Answer (score 0):

If you like to use a nice feature of python, you could use a generator for memory efficiency:

```
from random import randrange

def onetworandom(length):
    yield 1
    yield 2
    for i in range(length-2):
        yield randrange(0,10)

myvalue = [x for x in onetworandom(10)]

print myvalue
[1, 2, 8, 2, 9, 2, 6, 7, 6, 1]
```